# Pandas, create a create a dataframe with converting string columns to integers

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following CSV file I'm importing into a Pandas DataFrame

[image: CSV File]

It's not shown here but the data types are strings.

So, when I try to change the data types to integers when I'm initiating the DataFrame I get an error:

```py
DTYPES = {
    'Money(ILS)': TypesConsts.FLOAT,
    'Money(USD) ': TypesConsts.FLOAT,
    'Total Invested(USD) ': TypesConsts.FLOAT,
    'Nominal(USD)': TypesConsts.FLOAT,
    'Realized(USD)': TypesConsts.FLOAT,
    'Years Past(Years)': TypesConsts.FLOAT,
    'Tot Time(Years)': TypesConsts.FLOAT,
    'Charges(USD)': TypesConsts.FLOAT,
    'Actual Money(USD)': TypesConsts.FLOAT,
    'VHVE(Amount)': TypesConsts.INT,
    'VHVE(Purchase)': TypesConsts.FLOAT,
    'VHVE(Per Unit)': TypesConsts.FLOAT,
    'AAPL(Amount)': TypesConsts.INT,
    'AAPL(Purchase)': TypesConsts.FLOAT,
    'AAPL(Per Unit)': TypesConsts.FLOAT,
    'Margin left(USD)': TypesConsts.FLOAT,
    'Margin added(ILS)': TypesConsts.FLOAT,
    'Gross Profit(USD)': TypesConsts.FLOAT,
    'Net. Profit(USD)': TypesConsts.FLOAT,
    'Total Charges': TypesConsts.FLOAT
}

DATES_COL = ['Date']


class OrderData:
    df = pd.read_csv(PATH,
                     dtype=DTYPES,
                     parse_dates=DATES_COL
                     )
```

I get the following error:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '₪77,000.00'
```

I don't want to use pd.astype for every single column and after initiating the DataFrame.

So I can change the data types on the DataFrame creation?

Answer (score 0):

Your error is coming because of the Unicode character, that is why it can't be converted to `float`. Clean your strings before you try to convert to `float`.

Comment: Is there a way to this in python? 
since converting each cell is not realistic.